# break a long number into separate ints

Tags: java

I am trying to make a sorting system for an old archive. But i cant seem to figure out how to break a 47 digit number (`09281746381927384678172917289371628937821936782`)
into different `int`s as I want the parts of the number to meant things like row, year, department... And I will be printing it to a barcode. So I want to break that long number into its individual parts like

```
long one = 198610240984874358;
int year = one(0 + 1 + 2 + 3);
int month = one(4 + 5);
```

or something of the sort. I cant seem to find an answer online.

Comment: If you convert that number to a String, it would be easier to extract parts of it using `substring`.

Comment: You will have to keep that "number" as a String, if there is a possibility that it starts with zero, as any numerical representation is going to lose those initial zeros. It really isn't a number - it's a string of digits and you should treat it as such.

Comment: For your example, `int year = one / ((long)Math.pow(10, 14));` would work, but it is far better to keep that number as String. BTW, how do you receive it in your program? From a file?

Comment: I'll be using a barcode so a reader or maybe a mobile app with the barcode scanner api, not so sure yet but i got the problem and I need to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the best thing is to keep it as `String` and use `substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` to separate the numbers. Try,

```
long one = 198610240984874358l;
String number = one + "";

int year = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(0, 4));
int month = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(4, 6));
```

---

Read [Substring in Java](https://www.javatpoint.com/substring), to know more.